# How to convert groupby query to linq and compute other thing while executing?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this sql query and I want to convert it to linq.

```
SELECT [Scheme_Code], [FundFamily], [Scheme_Name], MAX([Date]) as LastDate   
FROM [MFD].[dbo].[MFDatas]   
GROUP BY [Scheme_Code], [Scheme_Name], [FundFamily]  
ORDER BY [Scheme_Code]
```

I want to check last date and if it's latest then I have to mark it as 'live'?

Comment: how do you determine last date is latest? last date falls in current month or year??

Comment: Okay but how to convert that query to linq?

Comment: max date, if there is dff between max date and current date is more than 10 days, then that date is not latest.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to copy results to `DataTable`, this query does what specified in your `Sql` query and copies results to `DataTable`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("Scheme_Code", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Scheme_Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("FundFamily", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("LastDate", typeof(DateTime));

var table = MFDatas.GroupBy(g=> new { Scheme_Code, Scheme_Name, FundFamily})
                   .Select(s=> 
                   { 
                        var row = dt.NewRow();
                        row["Scheme_Code"] =  s.Key.Scheme_Code, 
                        row["Scheme_Name"] = s.Key.Scheme_Name, 
                        row["FundFamily"] = s.Key.FundFamily, 
                        row["LastDate"] = s.Max(m=>m.Date) 
                    })                  
                   .OrderBy(o=>o.Field<string>("Scheme_Code"))
                   .Distinct()
                   .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: max date, if there is dff between max date and current date is more than 10 days, then that date is not latest.

Comment: Thanks for query, how to retrive it's result and save that to table? foreach and var ?

Comment: There were some errors to your new block so I have changed it to it like "var v = db.MFData.GroupBy(x => new { Scheme_Name = x.Scheme_Name, Scheme_Code = x.Scheme_Code, FundFamily = x.FundFamily, Date = x.Date })
                       .Select(group => new
                       {
                           Scheme_name = group.Key.Scheme_Name,
                           Scheme_Code = group.Key.Scheme_Code,
                           FundFamily = group.Key.FundFamily, 
                           Date     =       group.Key.Date

                       }

                       ); "  will it work

Comment: var v = db.MFData.GroupBy(x => new { Scheme_Name = x.Scheme_Name, Scheme_Code = x.Scheme_Code, FundFamily = x.FundFamily, Date = x.Date })
                       .Select(group => new
                       {
                           Scheme_name = group.Key.Scheme_Name,
                           Scheme_Code = group.Key.Scheme_Code,
                           FundFamily = group.Key.FundFamily,
                           Date = group.Max(x => x.Date)
                       }
                       ).OrderBy(x => x.Scheme_name);

Comment: Hey that last query is working ! Thanks a ton. I am bit confused with linq things, I hope you won't mind if I ask you questions in the future as well. :)

Comment: How can I loop that var in the for loop? I have to assign this result to data table

Comment: I'm outside give me few minutes, that's easy.

Comment: Sure, :) well, I did this one for latest date  "private bool isLive(DateTime d)
        {
            TimeSpan t = d - DateTime.Now;
            double c = t.TotalDays; 

            if(c > 20.0)
            {
                return true; 
            }

            else
            {
                return false; 
            }
        }"

Comment: If you won;t mind I'd like to ask you another query.

Comment: Dude, there is some issue with query, one I posted gives the distinct column names but one you suggested doesn't return distinct results

Comment: It says " Scheme_Code, Scheme_Name, FundFamily " don't include exist in current context

Comment: I assumed you have those columns in your query, replace with the column names you defined in `C#`